# How do I enable PHP on Mountain Lion and view a PHP file?

Tags: php, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I followed [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/10/enable-php-apache-mac-os-x/) guide to enable PHP on Mountain Lion, but now I have no idea where to access the page. I tried `localhost/~myusername/info.php` where info.php if my file, but nothing loads.

Comment: you need to elaborate a bit more on this. Does nothing loads mean that you get a server timeout, does it show some other error, or? Have you made sure apache is actually running?

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information to help you. But if you want a php/sql server on your mac i can recommend you [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/). A simple program that offers you to simple enable/disable Apache/PHP/SQL on your Macintosh.